# how to display "no result found" list search in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is work fine..any idea about how to display "no result found"..

**Here my code** http://jsfiddle.net/UI_Designer/8p426fog/4/

```
 $(".my-textbox").keyup(function() {
        var val = $(this).val().toLowerCase()

        $(".personsMenu li").each(function(i) {
            var content = $(this).html();
            if(content.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) == -1) {
              $(this).hide()


            } else {
                $(this).show();



            }
        });
    });
```

Thank You..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More elegant and the simplest way it to add extra variable and add `<div class="no-results" style="display:none">no results found</div>` into DOM, and then toggle visibility of the block  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8p426fog/9/)

```
var $block = $('.no-results');
$(".my-textbox").keyup(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var isMatch = false;

    $(".personsMenu li").each(function(i) {
        var content = $(this).html();
        if(content.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) == -1) {
           $(this).hide();           

        } else {
            isMatch = true;
            $(this).show();

        }
    });

    $block.toggle(!isMatch);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the below code for no result found.

```
$(".my-textbox").keyup(function() {
   var val = $(this).val();
   $(".personsMenu li").each(function(i) {
      var content = $(this).html();
      if(content.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) == -1) {
         $(this).hide();
         $(".personsMenu").html("<ul><li><label> NO RESULT FOUND!</label></li></ul>");                  
      } 
      else {
        $(this).show();          
      }
    });
 });
```

Hope this fullfill your requirement.

Comment: This can't work the expected way with just looking at your code. Did you even test it, I guess not...